# Http Error-Code 500 coming even when error page has been declared in DD

Tags: java, jsp, internet-explorer, tomcat

In the DD (web.xml) there's

```
  <error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/Common/error/GeneralError.jsp</location> 
 </error-page>

 <error-page> 
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/Common/error/GeneralError.jsp</location> 
 </error-page>

 <error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/Common/error/GeneralError.jsp</location> 
 </error-page>
```

but, while I am injecting some parameters in request, a custom exception generated reaches GeneralError.jsp (as per the logs). But, in IE, I am getting http status 500 error page.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's the same case or not, but could you try to make your error page like more than 512 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

It is the IE "Friendly HTTP Error Page" that you are seeing. 
Turn it off to see your custom error page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294807

Comment: It would be great if you could briefly summarize the steps needed, just in case that the link is unavailable.